# Without height and width list not shown in sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my code when i mentioned specfic height and width to to only that it shown.

```
{
                        xtype: 'list',
                        itemId : 'propertyListId',
                        height : 600,
                        width : 1200,
                        store: 'PropertyListStore',
                        itemTpl: '{PropertyId}',
                        style: 'background-color: white;',

                    }
```

Please any one suggest me?

Comment: list must be in fit or card layout.

Comment: Not resolved !!WARN][Ext.Base#callParent] Attempting to create a DataView with a layout. DataViews do not have a layout configuration as their items are laid out automatically.

Answer (score 0):

create panel in outside you list, and set panel layout = fit

```
layout: : 'fit',
items: [{
    xtype: 'list',
    itemId : 'propertyListId',
    store: 'PropertyListStore',
    itemTpl: '{PropertyId}',
    style: 'background-color: white;',
}]
```